# Design Schmitt Trigger

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger

Use Schmitt trigger to design a 1 kHz square wave oscillator. Assume the Op Amp supply voltages to be +15V, and the maximum bias current of the Op Amp to be 500nA. Assume that the maximum output of the oscillator to be +-14V.

This is what I have solved so far,
The bare circuit i have drawn is as below,but what does the 500nA use for?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJePlU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For R1 and R2 is it true for me to set any value but the same magnitude?

Comment: Yikes! That's a lot of current thru R1 and R2.  Are you sure your opamp can drive a 200 Ohm load?  Why not the usual knee-jerk 10 kOhms, or at least 1 kOhms for each?

Comment: How about the R3 and C, what value should I set?

Comment: We don't just give you answers to homework problems here.